# Safari, TypeScript, Angular2: const keyword are not supported in strict mode

Tags: javascript, typescript

I develop a web site using Angular2 + TypeScript.
When I use Google Chrome, my application is properly working.
But, when I use Safari, it displays the following message and my application doesn't work.

```
const keyword are not supported in strict mode
```

My tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "public/js",
    "module": "system",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "files": [
    "./src/ts/main.ts"
  ]
}
```

There is full source code in [my github repository](https://github.com/c-bata/c-bata.github.io).

Comment: Hi did you got the solution for the same?

Comment: Maybe take a look in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37228893/10198772).