# Why is my JavaScript not working correctly in strict mode on Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, macos, safari, strict-mode

I have built a website that uses some simple JavaScript. After some testing, I have found that my JavaScript is behaving very differently on iOS devices as compared to all other devices that I could test with.

After several hours of trial-and-error, I have discovered that the unexpected behaviour occurs only in strict mode, but it has been very hard to troubleshoot the problem further because I am limited in my software/hardware for Apple development and testing.

Why could my code not be working in strict mode, and only certain (Apple, in particular) devices?

Comment: Any hint as to what the code is?

Comment: I really just wanted to post this question in combination with the answer I gave because I think it may be able to help someone in the future who is having the same or a similar problem. For this specific case, I do not think that the code is entirely relevant.

Answer (score 4):

### The possible problem

Your problem may be that you have made a `const` declaration with strict mode enabled.

---

### A possible solution

If that is the case, and you would like to continue using strict mode, one solution is to use `var` instead of `const`, and simply be more careful to treat the variable as a constant.

---

### More on this problem

It is in fact difficult to debug this problem without an OS X computer, because you are unable to use iOS Safari's remote console "Web Inspector".

However, [according to caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=const), for the current versions of both Safari and iOS Safari (9.1 and 9.3, respectively, as of writing) `const` is:

> Only recognized when NOT in strict mode

You can test this for yourself using the following example ([or this JSFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/d6m51sjn/)). This code worked as expected for me with Chrome and Firefox on both Ubuntu and Android, but not on Firefox for iOS or iOS Safari.

HTML

---

```
<pre></pre>
<form>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

JS

---

```
"use strict";

var form = document.querySelector("form");
var info = document.querySelector("pre");

// This const declaration in conjunction with strict mode will
// cause this script not to work on iOS devices
const _MEANINGLESS = 0;

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    info.textContent = "Submit event captured.\n";
});
```